# How to Prove one Random Number Generator is Better Than Another?

Tags: algorithm, random, numbers, theory

How do you prove that one RNG is better than another?

I don't mean in terms of runtime, but rather the amount of entropy "generated" - which also rolls in the notion of periodicity (low period = low entropy).

Can a RNG be provable optimal? Or is this an unobtainable goal? By optimal, I mean any sequence is equally likely and independent of past or future results.

I'm interested in algorithms, not cosmic background sampling devices or other sources of physical "randomness" (is it random or just complex?)

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no way to prove "optimal" randomness.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_randomness#Tests

Comment: NIST provides documentation and software for testing randomness of RNGs:  http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/index.html .. The document is here, and describes 15 different RNG tests:  http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/documents/SP800-22rev1a.pdf

Comment: Don't think in terms of optimality, think in terms of suitability for a purpose. What purpose are you putting the RNG to? What are your constraints? This will determine which algorithm to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old standard for testing used to be the "Diehard tests." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests This has been superceded by the NIST tests that DKnight pointed out: http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/index.html. The Diehard wiki article gives you a good overview of the kind of things that are looked at. The NIST bit will take a bit more digging.

As you state it, no pseudo RNG (algorithm) can be proven optimal. They all have a seed value and are dependent on the input to generate a value. If you know the seed and the state, you know the next value. As an example, check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister. I like it mostly because of the awesome name, but the article does a good job explaining the tenets of a PRNG.

Answer (score 9):

See http://www.random.org/analysis/

The one and only optimal RNG:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The National Institute of Standards and Technology has some good info on this:

http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/index.html

Looks like there is a test suite and lots of good reference material

Answer (score 3):

There is an objective definition from computational complexity theory: the asymptotic time complexity required to distinguish the output from random data.

A good PRNG should force a distinguisher to spend lots more time as the size of the seed increases or as the level of certainty required increases. (With fixed size seeds I suppose you'd look at the actual running time as well as the program complexity.)

- For comparing one PRNG against another, the one with a smaller/faster distinguisher is worse.
- One common assumption, even though it's not been proven, is that some PRNGs are indistinguishable from random in polynomial time. That's one possible meaning for 'optimal'.
- Statistical tests, like the [diehard tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests), are just simple distinguishers.

Answer (score 1):

The basics are in Knuth, The Art of Computer Programming Vol 2, "Seminumerical algorithms". The idea is to devise tests of randomness where each test will try to find non-random aspects of a PRNG. Note that what might seem to be random to a human being is not. For instance, we tend to say that the sequence '1,4,4,1' for instance is non-random, whereas it may occur perfectly on a larger random sequence.

So the approach is roughly:

- Find different tests for randomness, this is essentially DieHard and NIST test groups.
- Execute said tests on the PRNG.
- If the PRNG fails one or more of the tests it can be perceived as a weaker PRNG than ones that survives.

A cool example of a test is phase-space analysis. Here is a link of it executed some years back on TCP randomness generators for different operating systems:

http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/oldtcp/tcpseq.html

Other classical tests are chi-squares, Komolgorov-Smirnoff etc, all explained in Knuth. Good PRNGs survive any conceivable attack on them.

Answer (score 0):

Generate sequences of numbers and then try to compress them. The more random ones will compress less. Pure randomness is incompressible. It would be interesting to see the results, and if there are going to be differences.

Comment: It would depend a lot on the compression algorithm. I suspect that most compression algorithms are not "smart" enough to compress even bad random number sequences. On the other hand, it is easy to compress many completely random sequences. The digits in pi are thought to be random, yet it is trivial to "compress" this sequence.

Comment: See @marcog's answer. Who is to say that in 1,000,000 runs getting 1,000,000 4's is any less random then any other result. Less *likely* results do not mean less *random*

Comment: @asawyer True. But I guess any randomness test will give you a bad result when presented to 10^6 equal numbers ... :D

Comment: @pafcu: a PRNG which outputs the digits of pi is *not* a good random number generator, so I think the example is irrelevant. A compression algorithm that compressed it would *correctly* identify the data as "bad".  @asawyer: specifically, if your PRNG gives you a million 4s (or any other specific sequence that you guessed in advance) you say that the generator is bad *with extremely high confidence*. If that level of confidence isn't good enough for you, don't take prescription medication, or expect gravity to work.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Books containing digits of pi have been sold specifically as a source for random numbers. Can you tell me _why_ pi is a bad generator? Just because it has only one possible sequence does not make that sequence any less random. As a bonus it has an infinite period.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: When talking about algorithms, proof usually mean _mathematical_ proof, not experimental proof. No matter how high the confidence is, it's not a valid _proof_.

Comment: @pafcu: it's a bad generator because you can look up the sequence in a book (or generate it yourself), and then predict the next value. If we're talking about a PRNG being "optimal", that means for one thing that it should be suitable for cryptographic work. No sequence out of a published book is suitable for cryptographic work. It doesn't matter how "good" or how "random" the mechanism used to generate it was, a fixed, published sequence isn't a good PRNG, any more than that XKCD joke.

Comment: And regarding algorithms I think that what you say is plain false. If a particular machine spits out a million 4s, then after the first half a million you should have stopped using it as a PRNG. Regardless of whether you can think of a "proof" that it is useless, it is in fact useless, and you'd be an idiot to persevere with it. The most likely explanation why you can't prove it's poor, in that circumstance, is that your model of the machine is incorrect, so it's irrelevant what you can or can't prove about any algorithm.

Comment: Going back to your original comment, though: the definition of "random" used in saying "the digits of pi are random", is not necessarily the same as the definition of "random" used in saying, "Blum Blum Shub is a good PRNG". I don't know whether using very distant digits of pi works as a PRNG - possibly it does, but certainly the use of dead-tree-published "random tables" isn't relevant to modern methods. A PRNG takes a seed value, such that without knowing the seed you "can't" predict the stream. That's what PRNGs do. No fixed sequence has this property.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: You are confusing cryptographically secure and optimally random RNG:s. A RNG can be cryptographically secure without being "optimal" and "optimal" without being cryptographically secure. Randomness is lack of correlation, _not_ impossibility to predict (although in some uses that certainly is an important characteristic).

Comment: @pafcu: I don't think you appreciate the difference between a sequence, and a generator of sequences. A sequence is not random. A generator (perhaps using the digits of pi in some way) can be random.

Comment: And a random number is not trully random because it is contained within a domain. For example a "random" byte can only exist with values 0..255 so it is not mathematically random, but numerically random. A mathematically random number must belong in the domain of ALL real numbers.